# Tables from Word 2007 are chopped off in 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013

I'm merging several documents together from various text editors. Some of the tables from Word 2007 don't display correctly in Word 2013, the right side gets cut off. See image below. Any idea why this would happen?

I checked to see if the right margins are negative and I don't believe they are.

[image: Table]

Comment: Check the table properties. Is the table size or cell size set to percent and above 100% or set to a fixed value that is greater than the width of the page?